# how to connect ANTLRWorks output to c# project?

Tags: c#, parsing, antlrworks

i have written a grammar for while in ANTLRWorks 1.5.2.
i also added some actions so when i debug my code with a while code it will show 3 address code in output of ANTLRWorks.
my grammar is like that:

```
NAME: 
LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')*;
NUMBER: 
 DIGIT+; // just integers
fragment DIGIT: 
'0'..'9';
fragment LETTER: 
'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z';
RELATION: 
'<' | '<=' | '==' | '>=' | '>' | '!=' ;
WHITESPACE: 
(' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ { $channel = HIDDEN; };
```

and i generate my grammar and i have whileParser.cs and whileLexer.cs in output folder.
now i want to add my grammar to a c# project.
i want to get input from user and then show output of my grammar to them.
and i dont know how to add .g file and output classes to a c# project.
i am using visual studio 2013.
can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You grammar contains Java code blocks, you need to translate them to C# first. Actually, it may be a good opportunity for you to use ANTLR 4 instead and/or to switch to a parse tree approach. I should mention there's an [ANTLRWorks 2](http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks) version, mostly for ANTLR 4, should you need it.

Anyway, just install the [ANTLR Visual Studio Plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f) and let it handle that for you. It works with both ANTLR 3 and 4.

You'll then have to add the ANTLR runtime to your project. For this, you can install the [ANTLR4 NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4) or the [ANTLR3 version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr3) depending on what version you chose to use in the end.